# Using Imputer in a Pipeline doesn't remove NaNs, gives ''Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')''

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, nan

So I'm using a pipeline to perform a Ridge Regression on some data, which also includes an imputer to remove the NaNs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

#making Data ready
gapdata = pd.read_csv('/Users/naveedanwer/desktop/Python Files/Life Expectancy Data.csv')
gapdata.columns = gapdata.columns.str.strip()
gapdata.rename(columns={'Life expectancy':'life'}, 
                 inplace=True)
gapdata.Status = gapdata.Status.astype('category')

model_data = gapdata.drop('Country',axis =1)
model_data = pd.get_dummies(model_data)

#initialize imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)

#initializing regression model
reg = Ridge(alpha = 0.5, normalize = True)

#steps for pipeline
steps = [('imputation',imp),('Ridge',reg)]

#initializing pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

#target and feature variables
X = model_data.drop('life', axis = 1)
y = model_data.loc[:,'life']

#splitting into training and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The original data does contain a lot of NaN values, which is why the imputer is in place. However, the follow error is output after the code is executed:

```
Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')
```

Which indicates that there are still NaNs in the data, despite the presence of the imputer. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that your missing values in `gapdata` are coded as string `'NaN'` instead of the default `np.nan`? What happens if you use `imp = Imputer(strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)`?

Comment: Gives the same error!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few types of NaNs that can be present in the dataframe.

`Type 1: np.nan
 Type 2: math.nan
 Type 3: float('nan')`

When you try comparing the three with each other, they return False. So one thing you can do is to check if these NaNs were saved in a specific format in the CSV and then use that format for the `missing_value` argument.

You can also use the pandas fillna() function to impute values instead of the sklearn Imputer to see if it's a problem there. For example if you want to impute each column with the columns mean value something like this should work:

`df = df.apply(lambda x:x.fillna(x.mean(), inplace = True))`

Comment: Hmm so if you read your error again, it says input contains NaNs or infinite values. Have checked for `inf` values? I would check for both NaNs and inf values before and after you use the imputer. That can help you scope down the problem. 

To check for NaNs, be it any type of NaNs (not a string 'NaN') can be checked using the np.isnan() function, and infinite values can be checked using the np.isinf() function. 

`a = np.array([np.nan, math.nan, 1])
b = np.array([np.inf])
np.isnan(a)  #returns [True, True, False]
np.isinf(b)   #return [True]`

Comment: @TheFutureNav So maybe your data also has some infinite values as well, which can be handled in different ways just like NaNs.